# Monthly Scheduler in android

Tags: android, alarmmanager, repeatingalarm

I am new in Android technologies and  creating an app in which i have to give various scheduling options like (Daily ,Weekly and Monthly). I have done with daily and weekly but left with monthly. I have no idea how to do it please help

Comment: Use [`AlarmManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

Answer (score 0):

AlarmManger will have you covered for all of the above, but when dealing with long timespans you'll need to set up the alarms again after the phone is rebooted which is likely over the course of a month.

See the following
[Android AlarmManager after reboot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12512717/android-alarmmanager-after-reboot)

Comment: If you found this answer useful to you could you please accept?