# Repeating Alarm Manager After reboot

Tags: android, android-service, android-broadcast

i want to create broadcast AlarmManager(repeating) with Notification message.i pass my calender object from Pickers. If i don't reboot my device it works normally. However, when i reboot my device,as you know  my calander object will be null. How can i manage my repeating alarm after rebooting and how can i hold my Calendar schedules?
Thanks for your ideas.

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private static final int PERIOD = 10000;
final public static String ALARM_ID = "AlarmId";
final public static String NOTIFICATION_ID = "NotificationId";


@Override
public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent i) {

}

static void scheduleAlarms(Context ctxt,Calendar c) {
    AlarmManager alarManager = (AlarmManager) ctxt
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
//notification servise  
    Intent i = new Intent(ctxt, ScheduledService.class);
i.putExtra(ALARM_ID, 1);
i.putExtra(NOTIFICATION_ID, 1);

PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(ctxt, 0, i,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
alarManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC,c.getTimeInMillis(),PERIOD, pi);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android AlarmManager after reboot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12512717/android-alarmmanager-after-reboot)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to use a `BroadcastReceiver` and set it to respond to `BOOT_COMPLETED` messages. For example

**Register your BroadcastReceiver in the manifest**

```
<receiver android:name=".MyBootReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Handle the message within your code

**MyBootReceiver.java**

```
public class MyBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{
    private static final String TAG = "MyBootReceiver";

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onReceive");
        Calendar cal = this.getMyCalendar();
        this.scheduleAlarms(context, cal);
    }

    private Calendar getMyCalendar() {
        // get your calendar object
    }

    private void scheduleAlarms(Context ctxt, Calendar c) {
        AlarmManager alarManager = (AlarmManager) ctxt.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        //notification servise  
        Intent i = new Intent(ctxt, ScheduledService.class);
        i.putExtra(ALARM_ID, 1);
        i.putExtra(NOTIFICATION_ID, 1);

        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(ctxt, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        alarManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC,c.getTimeInMillis(),PERIOD, pi);
    }
}
```

This will reset your alarm schedule on boot.

Comment: dont forget to add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />