# [Android]Best practice for repeating tasks which start at boottime?

Tags: android, service, gps, alarm, repeat

I'm fairly new to android programming and my goal is to develop a simple thing for android for a friends company.
I don't even know if I should call it a service or repeating alarm or repeating task or whatever.
Okay so here is what I need.

The device boots up and at that moment every 5 minutes the current GPS location should be gathered and sent via a http-request. There shouldn't be any userinteraction! (Its for company vehicle tracking)

What would be the best practice that I can achieve this?
Could you point me to good sources?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Register broadcast receiver for bootup. Then use a repeating Alarm. Your exact solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18023966/3260244)

Comment: So I'd have a Broadcastreceiver which registers my Alarmmanager and the Alarmmanager will then call the GPS activity in interval? Do I understand that right?