# alarmmanager starts immediately

Tags: android, alarmmanager

i want to set an alarms every day of weeks at mighnight this is my code:

```
int notificationId = getNotificationId(); //it get a random number
Context context = rule.context;
Intent intent = ((Activity) context).getIntent();
long time = getRuleCalendar().getTimeInMillis();
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
     notificationId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
     alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pendingIntent);
} else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
     alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time,pendingIntent);
} else {
  alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time,pendingIntent);
}

public calendar getRuleCalendar(){
    Calendar calSet = Calendar.getInstance();
    calSet.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, calendarDay); //calendarDay change by day of weeks
    calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 1);
    return calSet
}
```

now my problem is that one alarm start immediately (now is after mighnight and it is ok for me i want to check today) but all other alarms start at wrong time.
why?

Comment: Read the [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) for alarm behavior.

Comment: Ok but where is the problem

Comment: You are setting a single alarm not repeating ? Am i right ? Then how you repeat it everyday of week ? Please explain then only i will be able to find a solution.

Comment: I want to set one alarm for day (7 alarm) at midnight with no repeat. first alarm start immediately and other alarms start on wrong time (today al 08:30).

Comment: What is calendarDay in getRuleCalender method . Post whole code

Answer (score 2):

The alarm will only fire immediately if you set the alarm in the past.
For example in your case you are setting alarm for 00:00 AM for today which is alway be a past date for today. 
So you have set set the alarm for next day 00:00 AM . For that just add 1 in **Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR**   .

```
 public Calendar getRuleCalendar(){
    Calendar calSet = Calendar.getInstance();
    calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calSet.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR,1);
    calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 1);
    return calSet;
}
```

And for setting repeated alarm You have to check out the [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).

If you are not aware of background behavior change in **Doze Mode** starting from android M. Then have a look at [Optimizing for Doze and App Standby](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html).

Comment: Let me know if it works or  if you need any help.Thx

Comment: i set alarms by add DAY_OF_YEAR to getRuleCalendar() method and set this alarms:

Comment: Mon Dec 18 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2017 time:1513551600001
Tue Dec 12 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2017 time:1513033200001
Wed Dec 13 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2017 time:1513119600001
Thu Dec 14 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2017 time:1513206000001
Fri Dec 15 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2017 time:1513292400001
Sat Dec 16 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2017 time:1513378800001
Sun Dec 17 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2017 time:1513465200001

Comment: i got only 1 alarm immediately and if i change data i do not have other alarm. for prevent doze situation i set alarm with setExactAndAllowWhileIdle() how you can see up.

Comment: **EDIT** if I reboot smathphone i have one alarm but why?

Comment: the reason you got only one alarm cause you are setting only one alarm. You are not using 
 Set repeating, Read the documentation . And for handling reboot read [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17941371/repeating-alarm-manager-after-reboot).