# Schedule an SMS to be sent at a predefined time

Tags: android, sms

I want to schedule an SMS to be sent at a specific date.

The device may be turned off and on any number of times before the specified date. (AlarmManager won't work)

If the device is turned off at the time of the specified date the device is to send it as soon as the device is turned back on.

The message will be sent to a list of people that may change before the date.

The message may be deleted or edited before the specified date.

Comment: Check for device reboot, restart the alarm http://stackoverflow.com/a/12512783/826657

Answer (score 0):

Use a service that stays in the background 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Comment: using a service to check the time every maybe 1 minutes or so to see if the date has been reached is not practical, any other ideas? Also I prefer not to reset alarms each time the device is booted.