# Running a task every few hours

Tags: android, timer, alarmmanager

I have a method that I need to run every few hours even if the user didn't reopen the app.
What is the best way to go? 
Should I use the Timer class or Alarm manager?
Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use **AlarmManager** to schedule services for this. See this [Vogella tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html#scheduleservice_scheduling).

Comment: Will this work even after the phone was reseted or force close of the app?

Comment: Nothing works anymore if someone resets the phone to factory settings. Force closing might kill the services for a while, but you can make it boot up again.

Comment: I didn't mean factory reset, I meant restarting the phone... Should I use a broadcast receiver for the restarting or will it work without it?

Comment: You need to register a broadcast receiver that listens to boot event and sets up the alarm again. See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12512717/android-alarmmanager-after-reboot

Answer (score 16):

Step 1: Define 'Service' class to define logic to be executed

Ste 2: Define BroadcastReceiver and add  in manifest xml. This is responsible for calling 'Service' class to do the task.

May be you need add intent action  `<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>` under  in manifest xml

Step 3: Use 'AlarmManager' to schedule to repeat

couple links might help 
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html#scheduleservice_scheduling

http://khurramitdeveloper.blogspot.in/2013/06/android-alarm-manager-to-start-service.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I would have accepted it but the other answer was first.

Comment: Thanks. No problem :), I would be happy if it helps you :)

Comment: @Jayasagar Why would you need a `Service`?

Comment: @fiddler to start it after phone reboot.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's really helpful!