# How to update database after every 24 hour in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

In my application I'm using a button to update my sqlite database but now I want to update my database automatically after every 24 hours. How can I do this? I tried using CountDownTimer but that does not work when my app isn't running. I tried pending Intent and Alarm Manager but it isn't working properly(P.S: I tested it for 10 seconds instead of 24 hrs). It works for the 1st time when I start my activity and then it stops and doesn't work. Here's the code I tried:

```
public class Activity_Settings extends ActionBarActivity{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(mActivity, MyAlarmService.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getService(mActivity, 0,   
 notificationIntent,0);

        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) 
          getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.cancel(contentIntent);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()
                + AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 1, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 
        1, contentIntent); 

  }
  }
```

Service class:

```
 public class MyAlarmService extends Service {



@Override

public void onCreate() {

// TODO Auto-generated method stub
      Intent mainIntent = new Intent(this,Activity_Settings.class);
Toast.makeText(this, "MyAlarmService.onCreate()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

// update database
}



@Override

public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

// TODO Auto-generated method stub

Toast.makeText(this, "MyAlarmService.onBind()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

return null;

}



@Override

public void onDestroy() {

// TODO Auto-generated method stub

super.onDestroy();

Toast.makeText(this, "MyAlarmService.onDestroy()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}



@Override

public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {

// TODO Auto-generated method stub

super.onStart(intent, startId);

Toast.makeText(this, "MyAlarmService.onStart()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}



@Override

public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {

// TODO Auto-generated method stub

Toast.makeText(this, "MyAlarmService.onUnbind()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

return super.onUnbind(intent);

}



}
```

Comment: add background service class and call after 24 hours update.

Comment: do you tried to set alam for 24 hrs ? if it works you can sync DB using the same code

Comment: I haven't tried it for 24 hours but I have tried it for 10 seconds and it isn't working properly. When I close my app, service stops.

Comment: Check out this link to learn scheduling of tasks : http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTaskScheduling/article.html

Answer (score 2):

You should use `AlarmManager` to schedule your task in service. 
Take these steps:

- Define and implement your method to update DB in a Service class.
- Define `BroadcastReceiver` that is responsible for calling Service class to do the task.
- In you activity use `AlarmManager` to schedule the task.

This [link](http://khurramitdeveloper.blogspot.in/2013/06/android-alarm-manager-to-start-service.html) does exactly (not exactly) what you want to do. Don't know much about [SyncAdapter](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html) so won't comment on it.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this :)

Comment: Hope this will help you and other visitors in future.

Answer (score 0):

Please check following link [Link Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19652778/running-a-task-every-few-hours). Some Basic thing to follow add service in repeat task using alarm manager then write broadcast receiver to receive boot event to again register repeat task because it will wipe your register event after phone restarts.

Answer (score 0):

well from my side one more way is that call that service while change device date.

while user will open application at that time check data and if date is changed then previous date then call service.

your 24 hr service will run in background and may take load also if it continuously check time and wait for 24 hr.