# Handler postDelayed in Android Service

Tags: android, android-service, android-handler, postdelayed

In my app there is a `Service` that is intended to run constantly in background once started. This service is started from an `Activity` and this is the `onStartCommand()` method:

```
MyService:
....

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    mHandler.postDelayed(new myRunnable(), scheduledTime);
}
```

I want to know if having a very big `scheduledTime`(lets say a couple of days in milliseconds), the `Handler` will still execute the `Runnable`?
Or should I better use the `AlarmManager` for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to know if having a very big scheduledTime variable (lets say it represents a couple of days), the handler will still execute the runnable?

Yes, if the service and the thread the `Handler` posts to will be alive by the time.

> Or should I better use the AlarmManager for this?

Yes.

Comment: If it is still gonna work, why should I better use AlarmManager then?

Comment: @Perroloco Please, see [does Alarm Manager persist even after reboot?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12034357/does-alarm-manager-persist-even-after-reboot), [Android AlarmManager after reboot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12512717/android-alarmmanager-after-reboot) and similar posts.