# Android alarmmanager set alarms in specific days and repeat them all the weeks

Tags: android, android-studio, alarmmanager, alarms

i making a app where you can set alarms . it actually works but just one time.
and i need to do more than once .im trying to do an class schedule alarms.

for example i have class mondays at seven , so i need to start the alarm every monday. but also i have another class tuesday and have to do it the same.

here is my code that works   pd-> rqs1 = 1

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, horai); // i put the hour with the interface
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,minutoi);///
       cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,dias.getSelectedItemPosition()+1);
        cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 2);



        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra("name", curso); // i put the name of the curso
      PendingIntent pendingIntent =
               PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(),
                      RQS_1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);


    AlarmManager alarmManager =
            (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);


    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            cal.getTimeInMillis(), 24 * 7 * 60 * 60 * 1000 , pendingIntent);`
```

so, i have been looking how to do it.
please help me . Thanks

Comment: have you solved it?

Comment: no i still trying to do it

Comment: Instead of using `setRepeating`, use only `set` and then in the broadcast onReceiver call the broadcast again

Comment: public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "BANANEALARM";
    Intent intent;
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    NotificationManager notificationManager;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {



        Log.i(TAG, "BroadcastReceiver has received alarm intent.");
        Intent service1 = new Intent(context, AlarmService.class);
        String id = intent.getStringExtra("name");
        service1.putExtra("name",id);
        context.startService(service1);




    }

}

Comment: That's nasty, I'll post an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1-** Replace this

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
        cal.getTimeInMillis(), 24 * 7 * 60 * 60 * 1000 , pendingIntent);`
```

with this:

```
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            cal.getTimeInMillis(), 24 * 7 * 60 * 60 * 1000 , pendingIntent);
```

**2-** Replace this

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent =
           PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(),
                  RQS_1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

with this:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent =
           PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(),
                  RQS_1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT );
```

**3-** Add this inside `onReceive`:

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("name", curso); // i put the name of the curso
  PendingIntent pendingIntent =
           PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(),
                  RQS_1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT );


AlarmManager alarmManager =
        (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);


alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
        cal.getTimeInMillis(), 24 * 7 * 60 * 60 * 1000 , pendingIntent);`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using **FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT** instead **FLAG_ONE_SHOT**.

Also make sure to reschedule the alarms after device reboot. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12512783/1405542) is a good example.