# Android AlarmManager not working after reboot

Tags: android, alarmmanager, reboot

I did every step as what i should do, but its still not working.
Situation:
I have a bootreceiver, which works.
I get the Test toast visible after reboot.
I also get visible in Toast after reboot: Test: + i. (i = pending intent)
I see it does every scheduleAlarm() but when i get to the time where it should be scheduled, the alarm wont start.

```
public class SampleBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
public static final String MY_PREFS_NAME = "alarmPrefs";
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

private PendingIntent pi;
long INTERVAL_WEEK = 604800000L;
private AlarmManager am;
Context mContext;
int servTimeH;
int servTimeM;
int yourTimeH;
int yourTimeM;
int difTimeH;
int difTimeM;
String timeH;
String timeM;
String dateandtime;
long delay = 120000L;
int day;
int i = 0;

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    mContext = context;
    editor = context.getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, 0).edit();
    //start shared pref get here in if method.
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(".Alarms", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    System.out.println("BOOL: " + sharedPref.getBoolean("Monday", false));
    Toast.makeText(mContext, "TESTTT", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    //boolean days
    monday = sharedPref.getBoolean("Monday", false);


    if(monday){
        day = 1;
        if(pl13) {
            i++;
            pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext.getApplicationContext(), i, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
            scheduleAlarm(day, 13, 00);
            showText("i: " + i);
        }
    }
}

public void scheduleAlarm(int dayOfWeek, int timeH, int timeM){


    ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(mContext, SampleBootReceiver.class);
    PackageManager pm = mContext.getPackageManager();

    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

    System.out.println("Repeat alarm");

    Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar calSet = (Calendar) calNow.clone();
    calSet.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, dayOfWeek);

    calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, (timeH + difTimeH));
    calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, (timeM));
    System.out.println("Cal set to:" + (timeH + difTimeH) + ":" + timeM);

    calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    if(calSet.compareTo(calNow) <= 0){
        //Today Set timeH passed, count to tomorrow
        calSet.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 7);
    }


    am = (AlarmManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, (calSet.getTimeInMillis()-delay), INTERVAL_WEEK, pi);




}

public void showText(String s){
    Toast.makeText(mContext, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

Comment: what is pl13 in if(pl13) {....}

Comment: @SHekharKG
pl13 is a boolean which is true.
Like i said in the question: Everything works. I get the toast displayed i: + i. But it wont schedule the alarm.

Comment: Have you initialised difTimeH, difTimeM, timeH, timeM ? And then print log of millis you are passing to setRepeating() .

I think that might be issue.

Comment: Sure it´s the correct time? What about `calSet.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 7);`?  The alarm will start in 7 days....

Comment: receive **BOOT_COMPLETED** broadcast and set your alarm again. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12512717/android-alarmmanager-after-reboot?rq=1